# Track subfolders with and without trailing slash in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I want to track subfolders in Google Analytics, which are on one to five levels.

Additional obstacle is, that subfolders don't own in 100% cases trailing slash and i need to track both kind of them, with and without trailing slash, based only on the subfolder level, also /a-1/ and /a-1, /a-1/b-2/ and /a-1/b-2 and so on.

Folders look like /a-1/ and /a-1, /a-1/b-2/ and /a-1/b-2, /a-1/b-2/c-3/ and /a-1/b-2/c-3, /a-1/b-2/c-3/d-4/ and /a-1/b-2/c-3/d-4, /a-1/b-2/c-3/d-4/e-5/ and /a-1/b-2/c-3/d-4/e-5, and i need to track both of /a-1/ and /a-1 etc.

My idea was to count slashes to get the level of subfolder and then to make clear whether there is a traling slash or not to get bot variants. According to this idea matching of two subfolders, /a/b/ and /a/b would contain two rules:

- if there are 3 slashes and the string ends up with slash
- if there are 2 slashes and the string ends up without slash

This one, `(.*\/){3}\/$`, should match strings, which have 3 slashes and end up with slash,

Another one, `(.*\/){2}[^\/]$`, should match strings, which have 2 slashes and end up without slash.

Both rules don't work, not alone, not joined together with the pipe, as `(.*\/){3}\/$|(.*\/){2}[^\/]$` - they just match something not expected.

Point me please to the solution, to the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

It becomes a real rule for me: barely i become exasperated with finding of a problem's solution and post a question at StackOverflow, directly after posting i find an answer by myself :)

Well, the regular expressions, which do the job together are two: first to define the nesting level, and the second to exclude nesting levels higher as the defined.

For example, we want to create a filter matching subfolders on second nesting level with and without trailing slash. They look like /a-1/b-2/ and /a1/b-2

1. Matching needed subfolders: `(/[^\s]+){2}?$`
2. Excluding subfolders from higher nesting level: `(/[^\s]+){3}?$`

To make subfolder statistics always and easy available, we create shortcuts for each filter combination.

Done - enjoy!